# PHP couldn't connect sql_srv

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-7, xampp

PHP SQL server not connect.

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 21 [code] => 21 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The parameter is incorrect. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The parameter is incorrect. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 21 [code] => 21 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Service");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($conn);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the official Microsoft documentation:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$databaseName, "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, 
"ColumnEncryption"=>"Enabled");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/using-always-encrypted-php-drivers?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Note: The Always Encrypted feature requires Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.